# jquery ui sortable ie 10

Tags: jquery-ui

How can I get the [jquery ui sortable demo](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) working in IE 10?  It's working in Firefox and Chrome.  In IE 10, it drags, but doesn't drop.

I tried:

```
    forceHelperSize: true,
    forcePlaceHolderSize: true,
    helper: 'clone'
```

IE 10.0.9200.16384, Windows 8 Professional 64-bit, default document rendering mode of Browser Mode: IE10, Document Mode: Standards

Comment: I am not seeing any problems with the example listed http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#entry-examples in IE 10

Comment: which OS?  I'm using IE 10.0.9200.16384, Windows 8 Professional 64-bit, default document rendering mode of Browser Mode: IE10, Document Mode: Standards

Comment: I am using the exact same configuration. Did you look at your developer console to see if there were any errors there ?

Comment: no errors, to be more specific, it drags, but doesn't drop.  It has to do with html elements.  I'm using li's.  It works here with div's. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UdXr4/

Comment: I edited your question. Take a look at my changes. Use capital letters and make your sentences grammatical. Don't try to fool the filter by just adding sentences complaining about the filter. It might get your question posted, but it won't help you get answers.